# What's wrong with my deleting duplicate rows code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have bunch of excel files (approximately 1000 files ) which I want to merge them together and delete duplicate rows of them.
I have the following excel vba macro to do this.

```
    Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\dalakada\Desktop\deneme google drive keywords 100 tane")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:N" & Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
If counter Mod 90 = 0 Then
    Call RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow
End If


Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
counter = counter + 1
Next
End Sub
```

With this sub, I just basically open each files in a specified folder and merge them into one excel file.
Everything works here.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells_EntireRow()
'PURPOSE: Remove the entire row of duplicate cell values within a selected cell range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer

'Optimize code execution speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Determine range to look at from user's selection
  On Error GoTo InvalidSelection
    Set rng = Range("B2:B1000000")
  On Error GoTo 0

'Ask user which column to look at when analyzing duplicates
  On Error GoTo InputCancel
    x = InputBox("Which column should I look at? (Number only!)", _
      "Select A Column", 1)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize code execution speed
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Remove entire row if duplicate is found
  rng.EntireRow.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=x

'Change calculation setting to Automatic
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLING
InvalidSelection:
  MsgBox "You selection is not valid", vbInformation
  Exit Sub

InputCancel:

End Sub
```

This is the removing duplicate rows sub.
This code works also independently. The problem is If I use this code combined with simpleXlsMerger code that I wrote. It does not work. And It gave me blank space worksheet.
What are your thoughts ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: looks like you're calling it to work on the book your code is in, you need to specify workbook and sheet when you define rng

Comment: can you refer me an example ?

Comment: make booklist public, then `set rng= booklist.activesheet.range("A1:A100")` think that will do it, not using excel at mo

Comment: look at public variables in vba

Comment: Thank you so much Nathav, it worked!

Comment: No probs, give me some points :)